# How to show tick marks and labels with grid line for the specific one on the X axis with Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Thank you for paying attention to this question.

I'd like to add the ticks and 3 labels with the gridline like the picture but I couldn't find the best solution to make the X-axis like the picture. Hope someone helps me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this for your labels array:

```
labels: [["jan", 20], "", "", "", "", "", ["jul", 20], "", "", "", "", "", ["jan", 21]],
```

and this to your options object:

```
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               callback: (label) => (label === "" ? null : label)
          }
      }]
    }
  }
```

will get the following result:
[image]

Since the tick marks are getting generated from the grid lines they dissapear too, dont know how you can fix that

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I'd like to remove the vertical gridlines only except Jul 20.
Is it possible?

Comment: Edited answer, its not perfectly what you want but it comes close

Comment: Thank you so much, but I need to show the tick marks only for other values.